# Reference: MySql Connector/Net Authentication to host using method 'mysql_native_password' failed

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, connector-net

I tried to figure out for a long time, what the following error message was about and why I could not connect - although any other means would succeed.

```
Authentication to host 'x.x.x.x' for user 'product' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'product'@'%' to database 'product'
```

The first part of the error message reads:

```
Authentication to host 'x.x.x.x' for user 'product' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed
```

you are very confused, and try checking your password style. You probably don't even look at the second part ever again.

**Actually, the first part is total bollocks. It has absolutely nothing to do with the error!**

**Move on to the seocnd part and my answer**

Comment: Have you find solve for this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Accepted my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of the error message

```
"Access denied for user 'product'@'%' to database 'product'"
```

can mean virtually anything in regards to access restrictions. There is no specific message on WHY you are not allowed.
Therefore, you have to check any of those possibilities:

- Is your username correct?
- Is your password correct?
- Do you use new-style passwords?
- Is the host you are connecting from allowed to connect to the server?
- Do you have access to the specified database?
- Do you have ANY typos in the connection string, or the database access rights?

I hope this list is extensive and helpful - if not, please edit or comment.